# Decontruct serialized data array from wp_options

Tags: plugin-development, array, options

I'm trying to decontruct (and recreate) a serialized option value in wp_options called 'my_options'

How would I build the array to recreate this option_value that currently exists for 'my_options'?

update_option('my_options', ?)

After the update, the wp-options table would hold this value for 'my_options':

```
a:3:{s:12:"my_widget-1";a:2:{ etc...
```

Comment: [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), but you shouldn't need it as get_option() will do that for you...

Comment: I'm placing it into the database for the first time. Its a one-time operation for presetting widget contents to a default starting point. Of course, after I've done that, I could call get_option as you suggest, but it won't be an option until I create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use it as-is because it will get double-serialized. So as per comment you unserialize it first and it will get serialized back when saved into option.

```
$array = unserialize( $stuff );
update_option('my_options', $array);
```

Comment: OK, so I just can't call update_uption('my_options','a:3:{s:12:"my_widget-1";a:2:{...etc') then right?

Comment: @N2Mystic you can't. It will be treated like string and run through serialization again.